# Mysterious ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on specific website, what's the cause?

Tags: networking, browser, certificate, https

I have three Windows 10 machines in my home network, one desktop (LAN) and two laptops (WLAN). I am trying to access a certain website (belastingdienst.nl, the Dutch tax agency website). Results (consistently, these are not flukes):

**Desktop:**
-Brave browser (Chromium-based): ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
-Internet Explorer: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
-Firefox: Works fine
-Internet Explorer: works fine

**Laptop 1:**
-Brave browser: Works fine
-Internet Explorer: Works fine
-Chromium: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET (when I connect via VPN to my office network it works fine)

**Laptop 2:**
-Brave browser: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
-Internet Explorer: Works fine

These results baffle me. I did some logging on the **Desktop** machine with Wireshark and noticed that the remote machine sends a reset package:

```
192.168.xxx.xx  85.159.98.33    TCP 66  62457 → 443 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TCP 62  443 → 62457 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=4260 Len=0 MSS=1420 SACK_PERM=1
192.168.xxx.xx  85.159.98.33    TCP 54  62457 → 443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0
192.168.xxx.xx  85.159.98.33    TLSv1.2 571 Client Hello
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TCP 60  443 → 62457 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=518 Win=4777 Len=0
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TLSv1.2 1474    Server Hello
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TCP 1474    443 → 62457 [ACK] Seq=1421 Ack=518 Win=4777 Len=1420 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TCP 1474    443 → 62457 [ACK] Seq=2841 Ack=518 Win=4777 Len=1420 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TCP 1474    443 → 62457 [ACK] Seq=4261 Ack=518 Win=4777 Len=1420 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TLSv1.2 657 Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Server Hello Done
192.168.xxx.xx  85.159.98.33    TCP 54  62457 → 443 [ACK] Seq=518 Ack=6284 Win=65320 Len=0
192.168.xxx.xx  85.159.98.33    TLSv1.2 180 Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TCP 60  443 → 62457 [ACK] Seq=6284 Ack=644 Win=4903 Len=0
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TLSv1.2 60  Change Cipher Spec
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TLSv1.2 99  Encrypted Handshake Message
192.168.xxx.xx  85.159.98.33    TCP 54  62457 → 443 [ACK] Seq=644 Ack=6335 Win=65269 Len=0
192.168.xxx.xx  85.159.98.33    TLSv1.2 1072    Application Data
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TCP 60  443 → 62457 [ACK] Seq=6335 Ack=1662 Win=5921 Len=0
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TCP 60  443 → 62457 [RST, ACK] Seq=6335 Ack=1662 Win=0 Len=0
```

I also did some logging on the working browsers. My machine, before sending application data, sends an additional "Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message" message to the remote machine.

It seems that the problem is caused by the fact that the remote machine expects to receive an additional TLS "negotiation" package, and in the absence of that sends a reset package back.

What's even weirder is the fact that on **Laptop 2**, I actually see a HTTP 302 error in Wireshark, followed by a reset package (no TLS packages / attempted handshakes at all):

```
192.168.xxx.xx  85.159.98.33    TCP 66  58207 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64952 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TCP 62  80 → 58207 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=4260 Len=0 MSS=1420 SACK_PERM=1
192.168.xxx.xx  85.159.98.33    TCP 54  58207 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64952 Len=0
192.168.xxx.xx  85.159.98.33    HTTP    507 GET / HTTP/1.1 
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  HTTP    189 HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily 
85.159.98.33    192.168.xxx.xx  TCP 56  80 → 58207 [RST, ACK] Seq=136 Ack=454 Win=0 Len=0
```

I find this thoroughly weird. How can I fix this or further diagnose the problem? What causes this behavior? The fact that this happens on three independent machines, but only when connected to my home network makes this a somewhat mysterious problem.

Comment: If you stumble on a fix (or explanation), do answer your own question; I have the same problem (connection reset) with belastingdienst.nl for quite a while.